# Activate javaScript in Windows Phone App

Tags: c#, javascript, visual-studio, windows-phone

I#m working on a Windows Phone App in Visual Studio, which displays a Webbrowser (similar to a Webview from Android or iOS). But this webbrowser cant run javascript? I suppose that it is like in eclipse, where I have to specific activate this function, but how could it be done?

Thanks.

Comment: What web browser are you talking about? Windows Phone app dev window has the design view (XAML) and code view.

Comment: I thought Windows Phone used Internet Explorer?  If that is the case it likely would be based on the user's settings to allow/disallow javascript.

Comment: @Ramhound yeah, i thought that too. but in fact the user is not able to deactivate/activate javascript, it is on by default, but not in my webview.

Comment: @Shoban i mean the design view (xaml)

Comment: I am little confused about using javascript in xaml. The design view as trhe name says is just the design VIEW and it does not execute javascript in Visual Studio. You can run it in Emulator. Are you talking about phone gap apps?

Comment: no. i mean i have a webview (its called webbrowser in visual studio) in my app which is just showing up a webpage which is on the internet (like www.google.at). and this website uses a little bit of javascript, just a button which is counting up, and that is not working in the app (on iphone or android it works well, at android i had to declare it that the webview is running javascript).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`WebBrowser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) control has an [`IsScriptEnabled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser.isscriptenabled%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) property that you must set to `true` to be able to use Javascript.